# MySQL - Oddities when doing a count, that I can't explain

Tags: sql, mysql

Doing a simple query I'm finding two very different results, and I'm not sure how I'm coming to this conclusion.  Below is the example, please let me know if its something I'm just over looking..

```
SELECT b.fkid as t, 
       b.timestamp, 
       count(b.fkid) as hits, 
       count(distinct(b.fkid)) as num, 
       DATE_FORMAT( b.timestamp,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS val1
  FROM a, b
 WHERE a.id = b.fkid
group by val1
```

...result:

```
2 2009-09-25 08:33:42 **27** 3 2009-09-25
```

...compared to:

```
SELECT b.fkid as t, 
       b.timestamp, 
       count(b.fkid) as hits, 
       count(distinct(b.fkid)) as num, 
       DATE_FORMAT( b.timestamp,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS val1
  FROM a, b
 WHERE a.id = b.fkid
group by t
```

..result:

```
2  2009-09-25 08:33:42 **39** 1  2009-09-25 
3  2009-09-25 08:36:59 **6**  1  2009-09-25 
10 2009-09-25 22:40:14 **4**  1  2009-09-25
```

I don't understand how 39+6+4 = 27? I am expecting the first value to be 49 not 27.
Also tried:

```
SELECT b.fkid as t, 
       b.timestamp, 
       count(b.fkid) as hits, 
       count((b.fkid)) as num, 
       DATE_FORMAT( b.timestamp,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS val1
  FROM a, b
 WHERE a.id = b.fkid
group by val1
```

...which produces:

```
2   2009-09-25 08:33:42     27      27      2009-09-25
```

Following recommendation from below I tried eliminating the irrelevant data and made the query:

```
SELECT count(b.fkid) as hits, 
       count(distinct(b.fkid)) as num, 
       DATE_FORMAT( b.timestamp,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS val1
  FROM a, b
 WHERE a.id = b.fkid
group by val1
```

...this produced:

```
27      3   2009-09-25
```

I've tried to simplify this down to:

```
SELECT count(b.fkid) as hits, 
       count(distinct(b.fkid)) as num
  FROM a, b
 WHERE a.id = b.fkid
group DATE_FORMAT( b.timestamp,  '%Y-%m-%d' )
```

...this produced:

```
27      3
```

and:

```
SELECT count(b.fkid) as hits, 
       count(distinct(b.fkid)) as num
  FROM a, b
 WHERE a.id = b.fkid
group b.fkid
```

...this produced:

```
39      1
6   1
4   1
```

Comment: whats "val1"? is that a standard or something that I dont know about?  or another field

Comment: val1 is just renaming DATE_FORMAT(b.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d) so i can group by val1 instead of grouping by DATE_FORMAT(b.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d).

Comment: oh... scrolling right wouldve helped

Comment: maybe the date, although not shown, carries milliseconds?

Comment: naw i force it into day format.

Comment: @Frederico: Please stop using <pre> tags for code - here the notation reference: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Fantastic thanks. Someone edited my code and placed <pre> tags in, so I continued to use those. Will use this way instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL you should group by all the fields that are not aggregates, not just val1.

MySQL lets you get away with not doing so(most other databases will throw an error) but it can leave you with unpredictable behavior like this , especially if val1 does not disinctly identify the aggregates you are producing.

Comment: Sadly, yes - selective group by behavior works as designed in MySQL.  There are numerous "why doesn't this work on my db when it works on MySQL" questions on SO :/

Comment: So, just to make sure I'm understanding this correctly, I should group by all fields that are not aggregates correct? I've done this in my last example, is there something differently I should be doing? Thank you again.

Comment: What you should be doing depends on what data you want, the queries given above just mentions they produces different results, but we need to know what data you actually want to help more.

Comment: After looking into this for a bit longer, I realized what you ment by the aggregated data.  I now have this working, and realized that by grouping by simply t, it was grouping all datas together.  I found this out by doing max(b.timestamp), which showed me that there was infact grouping all data together.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're counting distinct fkid values.  Can there be duplicates of that value?  That could change your numbers, I think.

Comment: I tried removing the distinct, this however then comes up with the value 27 in the count(distinct(b.fkid)) as num along with the original 27 value.

Answer (score 0):

**In the first query your grouping  by val1 which is the same for all the records, so you only see the first value of non aggregate functions.**

In the second query you are seeing 3 results -- the number of different fkid's

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

By formatting the date for val1, you are taking records with different timestamps (but the same calendar date) and grouping them. AKA the timestamp for "2009-12-01 01:00:00" and "2009-12-01 02:00:00" formatted with the DATE_FORMAT you specify both return "2009-12-01". BUT by not grouping on that date format in the second query, the records are staying separate.